# docker: No such file or directory after building the image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I just started going through the tutorial and trying to wrap up some of my codes into the docker. The question might sound familiar to many of you as I can see quite similar threat but unfortunately I couldn’t get my heads around so decided to write it here.

I have made a telegram chatbot using python. All files are under `/project/`. I have another folder under `/project/` `calledDockerTelegramChatBot` where I have the Dockerfile.

Inside the `DockerTelegramChatbot` I have two files the `Dockerfile` and `requirements.txt`.

The content of the `Dockerfile` looks like the following

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6-stretch

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app
ADD . .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --default-timeout=100

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD pwd

CMD ls
CMD python /app/main_bot.py
```

I build the image using

```
docker build -t simpletelegramchatbot DockerTelegramChatBot/
```

and run it with

```
docker run -p 4000:80 simpletelegramchatbot
```

The main question is how I can resolve the “No such file or directory after building the image”. But also, I wonder what is the best practice to troubleshoot such cases, if I edit the dockerfile, do I have to build it from scratch every time ? “pip install requirements” takes a few minutes and makes the whole process quite annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The main question is how I can resolve the “No such file or directory after building the image”.

Having built an image, it's straightforward to launch a container based on the image that runs an interactive shell instead of the CMD in the Dockerfile:

```
docker run --rm -it simpletelegramchatbot bash
```

(Footnote: this command line doesn't work if you routinely use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD, which is one of a couple of reasons I suggest CMD as a default.)

As you run `docker build` the output will also include a long hex number after each step.  These are valid image IDs, and you can use these in the `docker run` command to see what's going on in the middle of the build by getting a shell on the intermediate image built immediately after the COPY step, for example.

As you've described your project layout, it sounds like:

```
/project/
+-- main_bot.py
\-- DockerTelegramChatBot/
  +-- Dockerfile
  \-- requirements.txt
```

So when you run `docker build DockerTelegramChatBot`, it *only* sees that subdirectory, and if you look around the built image, you will probably only see the `requirements.txt` file.  Because of the internal build mechanics, it is actually impossible for Docker to access files in the parent directory.  Fixing this is straightforward enough: just move the two files up to the parent directory.

> if I edit the dockerfile, do I have to build it from scratch every time ? “pip install requirements” takes a few minutes

Yes; but, Docker will skip over a step if a previous `docker build` has started from an identical image and run an identical command.  This is called *layer caching*.  Critically, any COPY or ADD step will break layer caching if any of the files involved in it change.

A very common pattern is to COPY in a small number of files that describe how to get requirements (`requirements.txt`, `package.json`, `Gemfile`, ...), install the requirements, and then install the rest of the source.  This will cause Docker to only re-run the `pip install` step if the `requirements.txt` file changes.  Your Dockerfile might look like:

```sh
FROM python:3.6-stretch
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --default-timeout=100
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["./main_bot.py"]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Do I have to build it from scratch every time ? “pip install requirements” takes a few minutes and makes the whole process quite annoying.

**A:** You can build a base `docker image` with all your python programs already pre-installed. Then in your actual program's `Dockerfile` you would say `FROM xyz_img`, where xyz_img is the base image you built. This would essentially avoid having to go through the time consuming `pip install` again.

**Q:** How I can resolve the “No such file or directory after building the image”

**A:** Pretty sure there are many debugging tricks out for this. For me the easiest way is the make your docker container stay alive and connect into it to inspect the directories within it.

For **connecting**, you can do: `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash`.

To keep a running container alive, the easiest for your use-case would probably be to write python program that never exits. E.g. sleep for a minute wakes up and go back to sleep for another min.